# VB.NET Create and Close Forms after Certain Time

Tags: vb.net, forms, timer

I could easily close form after few seconds; but when I want to close many forms one after another, same sequence as they were "created";  I could not figure it out:
The main form code is as below:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim numberOfForms As Integer = 10
        For open = 1 To numberOfForms
            TestClosing()
        Next
    End Sub
```

The module code that I am trying to create then close forms after few seconds is as below:

```
    Imports System.Timers 
    Module ClosingModule
        Sub TestClosing()
            Dim frmNew As New Form
            frmNew.Show()
            Dim tmr As New System.Timers.Timer()
            tmr.Interval = 3000
            tmr.Enabled = True
            tmr.Start()
        End Sub
    End Module
```

I started a timer, but all the methods I tried to close the form is same sequence they were created; were not successful;
Help appreciated; and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the Timer to the Forms you are creating, start it when the Form is created that way they will be closed in the same order that they were created. I also added an incremental delay to that the order of closing is more evident.

**Form1**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numberOfForms As Integer = 10
    For open = 1 To numberOfForms
        Dim frmNew As New Form2
        frmNew.Text = open.ToString
        frmNew.Show()
    Next
End Sub
```

**Form2**

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim myTimer As New Timer()
    Private Sub myTimer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        myTimer.Stop()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        myTimer.Interval = 1000 * CInt(Me.Text)
        AddHandler myTimer.Tick, AddressOf myTimer_Tick
        myTimer.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Added code in module to do the same thing:

```
Imports System.Timers
Module ClosingModule
    Sub TestClosing(multiplier As Integer)
        Dim frmNew As New Form
        frmNew.Show()
        Dim tmr As New System.Timers.Timer()
        AddHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf Timer_Elapsed 'Add Handler to New Timer
        tmr.SynchronizingObject = frmNew 'Synchronize Timer to newly created form
        tmr.Interval = 1000 * multiplier
        tmr.Enabled = True
        tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Timer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        Dim tmr As System.Timers.Timer = DirectCast(sender, System.Timers.Timer)
        tmr.Stop() 'Stop Timer
        DirectCast(tmr.SynchronizingObject, Form).Close() 'Get Form Timer was synchronized with and close it
        tmr.SynchronizingObject = Nothing 'Remove Form reference from timer
        RemoveHandler tmr.Elapsed, AddressOf Timer_Elapsed 'Remove Handler from Timer
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Mark; Long time no see :) This code is working perfectly; except when I tried to put in my module, it did not work; Could you please help me to let me know how to modify it to work in the Module in my original code. Thanks again.

Comment: Mark; please discard my comment above; it is working perfectly; Much appreciated; +1. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help, was working on your comment. will post results should work the same.

Comment: Thanks Mark; may be better results; I will still be waiting for your next post... They are invaluable.

Comment: Thank You.  Personally I would prefer the first example, since everything is contained in the form and will be disposed with the form is closed.

Comment: Yes mark; Agreed; and just one comment the "multiplier" in Module = "open" passed from Form1. I am going to play with both methods tonight. Thanks again.